# trouble populating classes generated by svcutil off wsdl

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization

UPDATE: 11/26/2012
I've updated my autogenerated c# classes using wsdl.exe instead of svcutil, so I could get SOAP attributes in the proxy classes (i'm calling a SOAP service).  My original problem was serializing, but with help from markus, I'm able to serialize now. But now I get an error back from the service:

Invalid request object: It must be a Query Request

The xml which works when I hard-code it:

```
<xml version="1.0"?><Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Header/><Body>
<QueryRequest xmlns="http://emkt.pjm.com/emkt/xml">
<QueryMarketResults type="Virtual" day="2012-11-16"><All/>
</QueryMarketResults></QueryRequest></Body></Envelope>
```

The xml it's generating is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<QueryRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://emkt.pjm.com/emkt/xml">
  <QueryMarketResults day="2012-11-16" type="Virtual">
    <All />
  </QueryMarketResults>
</QueryRequest>
```

I'm missing the envelope and body tags. I tried serializing as below, but got error "there was an error generating the XML document".

```
XmlTypeMapping myTypeMapping = (new SoapReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(typeof (QueryRequest)));
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(myTypeMapping);
```

Here are the relevant proxy classes: (I added the [XmlRoot] attributes below on QueryRequest which did add the correct namespace)

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=false, Namespace="http://emkt.pjm.com/emkt/xml")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://emkt.pjm.com/emkt/xml")]
public partial class QueryRequest {

    private object[] itemsField;

    private ItemsChoiceType1[] itemsElementNameField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("QueryPortfolios", typeof(QueryPortfoliosType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("QueryVirtualBid", typeof(QueryByAllLocationDayType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemsChoiceType1[] ItemsElementName {
        get {
            return this.itemsElementNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsElementNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://emkt.pjm.com/emkt/xml", IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemsChoiceType1 {
    QueryPortfolios,
    QueryVirtualBid,
}
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The constructors does not assign any value to the arrays, so they will be null.

Try this:

```
var qr = new QueryRequest
{
    ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType1[] {
        ItemsChoiceType1.QueryMarketResults,
    },
    Items = new object[] {
        new QueryByAllLocationDayTypeType
        {
            ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType3.All,
            Item = new QueryAllType(),
            day = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-11-16"),
            type = MarketQueryTypeType.Virtual,
        },
    },
}
```

Or, equivalently without object initializers:

```
var qmr = new QueryByAllLocationDayTypeType();
qmr.ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType3.All;
qmr.Item = new QueryAllType();
qmr.day = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-11-16");
qmr.type = MarketQueryTypeType.Virtual;

var qr = new QueryRequest();
qr.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType1[1];
qr.ItemElementName[0] = ItemsChoiceType1.QueryMarketResults;
qr.Items = new object[1];
qr.Items[0] = qmr;
```

Comment: Thanks! Obviously a key concept I missed.  Well that serialized but it came back with an error message saying the class for the root element 'QueryRequest' could not be found.  The xml was: <QueryRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> ... I expected to see  xmlns="http://emkt.pjm.com/emkt/xml"   not w3.org ?

Comment: You are missing the attributes on `class QueryRequest`. If you look at `class QueryByAllLocationDayTypeType` you see how it should look like.

Comment: But the xml in fiddler looks just like the successful xml string. Everything is there but the xmlns is different. Here's the xml that fails:    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<QueryRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <QueryMarketResults type="Virtual" day="2012-11-19" xmlns="http://emkt.pjm.com/emkt/xml">
    <All />
  </QueryMarketResults>
</QueryRequest>

Comment: `<Envelope>` and `<Body>` are part of the SOAP protocol. You should look into web services and web service proxies. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d2s8y7bs(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I regenerated the classes using wsdl.exe and now the classes contain a lot of SOAP info.  But I'm still getting xml where the root is missing the namespace and the first child object contains the namespace.  I even added [XmlRoot] to the QueryRequest class.

Comment: Does `<QueryRequest>` have any namespace (`xmlns="..."`), either on itself, or any parent? The `xmlns:xsi=` and `xmlns:xsd=` will be ignored in any decent xml-parser.

Comment: What is the XML that is generated, and how does it differ from what you want? (Edit you question with the XML)

Comment: Thanks for all your help Markus.  I'm at my wits end and everything I try seems to generate the same xml posted at the top.  Really appreciate your help!!